# React native iOS build issue - glog - Use of undeclared identifier 'SYS_gettid'

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

My project was working fine until I forked a version of react-native and tried to setup the RNTester app on my local machine. I removed node_modules & tried to do a fresh install but nothing works. It fails always at

```
pid_t tid = syscall(__NR_gettid); -- Use of undeclared identifier 'SYS_gettid'
```

In the file /Pods/glog/utilities.cc.

I am breaking my head, any help is appreciated.

Things I tried so far,

https://github.com/openstreetmap/mod_tile/issues/114

[Mojave + Xcode 10 build fails on glog config.h, gflags/gflags.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896834/mojave-xcode-10-build-fails-on-glog-config-h-gflags-gflags-h)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long story short: remove Pods and hard remove Xcode cache.

Run `rm -rf ios/Pods`, then press `Cmd + Option/Alt + Shift + K` to hard clean Xcode project (with DerivedData). Then running `pod install` again should fix it.

Longer story:

`SYS_gettid` is not available on macOS, so React Native builds glog with an "arm-apple-darwin" host through `ios-configure-glog.sh` file that runs during `pod install` step: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.61-stable/scripts/ios-configure-glog.sh#L31. I'd say it's a CocoaPods issue that the script didn't kick in, but it's hard for me to verify it.